# ERROR: paused potential out of memory crash using karma.js

Tags: karma-jasmine, karma-runner

The error related with karma test runner

My karma.config.js

```js
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Tue Apr 26 2016 09:56:05 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
        basePath: '',
        // frameworks to use
        // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
        frameworks: ['jasmine-ajax', 'jasmine', 'requirejs'],
        proxies: {
            '/src/': '/base/src/',
            '/src/common': '/base/src/common',
            '/node_modules/': '/base/node_modules/',
            '/styles/': '/base/styles/'
        },
        reportSlowerThan: 500,
        // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
        files: [
            "test-main.js",
            { pattern: "src/common.min.js", included: true },
            { pattern: "spec/**/*.spec.js", included: false },
            { pattern: 'node_modules/es6-promise/dist/es6-promise.js', included: false },
           
        // list of files to exclude
        exclude: [
        ],
        // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
        // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
        preprocessors: {},
        // test results reporter to use
        // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
        // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
        reporters: ['dots', 'html'],
        // the default html configuration 
        // web server port
        port: 9876,
        // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
        colors: true,
        // level of logging
        // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
        autoWatch: true,
        // start these browsers
        // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
        browsers: ['ChromeHeadless', 'Chrome', 'Firefox'],
        // Continuous Integration mode
        // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
        singleRun: false,
        // Concurrency level
        // how many browser should be started simultaneous
        concurrency: Infinity,
        coverageReporter: {
            type: "html",
            check: {
                each: {
                    statements: 90,
                    branches: 90,
                    functions: 100,
                    lines: 90
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

**karma version**: 0.13.2

gulp task to run the test

```js
gulp.task('test', function (done) {
    new karma.Server({
        configFile: path.resolve('./karma.conf.js'),
        singleRun: false,
        browsers: ['Chrome'],
        browserNoActivityTimeout: 30000
    }, function (e) {
        done(e === 0 ? null : 'karma exited with status ' + e);
    }).start();
});
```

I'm getting below console error in jenkins

[HeadlessChrome 71.0.3578 (Linux 0.0.0)]: [39mDisconnected (1 times), because no message in 30000 ms.

And in browser I face the error

paused potential out of memory crash